# Setup Firebase function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a question about how to setup Firebase Function. From the
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSFNK.png). How can I use `firebase/config` in `functions/src`

Since, when I use the Firebase CLI it create the `Functions` folder outside of the `src` or should I move the `functions` folder under `/src` ?

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is that you're trying to solve, and how moving folders around might solve that problem.  Please edit the question to be more clear.